# Adapter doesn't fill recycler

Tags: android

I have a problem with recycler, the problem is: I have AsyncTask which query data from my db, and then updating recycler by CursorLoader, but adapter doesn't fill recycler, Logs says that the data from db is successfully reading and then Adapter constructor successfully takes ArrayList with data, but that's all, logs says that adapter's methods doesn't call.

**MainActivity** :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


private SQLiteDatabase db;
private SimpleCursorLoader loader;
private MySimpleAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recycler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);

    new SimpleTask(SimpleTask.OPEN, null).execute();
}

private class SimpleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public static final int INSERT = 0;
    public static final int DELETE = 1;
    public static final int OPEN = 2;
    private int task;
    private String name;

    public SimpleTask(int task, String name) {
        this.task = task;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        switch (task) {
            case INSERT :
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(SimpleHelper.KEY_NAME, name);
                db.insert(SimpleHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                break;
            case DELETE :
                db.delete(SimpleHelper.TABLE_NAME, SimpleHelper.KEY_NAME + " = ? ", new String[]{name});
                break;
            case OPEN :
                if (db == null) {
                    try {
                        db = new SimpleHelper(MainActivity.this).getWritableDatabase();
                    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        if (loader == null) {
            loader = new SimpleCursorLoader(MainActivity.this, db);
            loader.setQueryParams(SimpleHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{SimpleHelper.KEY_NAME},
                    null, null);
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, MainActivity.this);
        }
        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    Log.i("MyLog", "onLoadFinished cursor size is " + data.getCount());
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    data.moveToFirst();
    do {
        items.add(data.getString(0));
        Log.i("MyLog", data.getString(0));
    } while (data.moveToNext());

    Log.i("MyLog", "onLoadFinished items size is " + items.size());

    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(items);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        adapter.updateAdapter(items);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}

private class MySimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MySimpleAdapter.MyHolder> {

    private List<String> items;

    public MySimpleAdapter(List<String> items) {
        Log.i("MyLog", "Constructor called with items size " + items.size());
        this.items = items;
    }

    public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView tvText;

        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new SimpleTask(SimpleTask.DELETE, tvText.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    public void updateAdapter(List<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.i("MyLog", "onCreateViewHolder");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvText.setText(items.get(position));
        Log.i("MyLog", "onBindViewHolder setText : " + items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("MyLog", "getItemCount called with size : " + items.size());
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

**SimpleCursorLoader :**

```
public class SimpleCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

private SQLiteDatabase db;
private String tableName;
private String[] columns;

public SimpleCursorLoader(Context context, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super(context);
    this.db = db;
}

public void setQueryParams(String tableName, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.columns = columns;
    setSelection(selection);
    setSelectionArgs(selectionArgs);
}

@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground() {
    Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, columns, getSelection(), getSelectionArgs(),
            null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

**DBHelper** :

```
public class SimpleHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "users";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DB_NAME = "SimpleDB";

public SimpleHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "("
    + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + KEY_NAME + " text)");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, "name" + i+1);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Log.i("MyLog", "inserted");
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

**activity_main.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); 
recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, cant bealive that i forgot to setLayoutManager